# Ember - different keys for serialization and deserialization

Tags: serialization, ember.js, ember-data, deserialization

I have an issue where an property needs to be serialized and deserialized using to different keys.

In the **`serializer`**, the property addresses the key `trade`:

```
'tradeId': { key: 'trade' },
```

This works when addressing the *deserialization* endpoint.

However, for *serialization*, the endpoint property is called `trade-identifier`, requiring the serializer reference to be changed to the following:

```
'tradeId': { key: 'tradeIdentifier' },
```

Is there any way to define seperate keys for serialization and deserialization in an Ember serializer?

Comment: The serialize and normalizeResponse hooks should help you out. See https://guides.emberjs.com/release/models/customizing-serializers/#toc_customizing-serializers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @handlebears for pointing me in the right direction here.
Simply adding a [serialize](https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember-data/release/classes/DS.JSONAPISerializer/methods/serialize?anchor=serialize) method to the governing serializer file allowed me to reassign the data to the appropriate JSON property:

```
serialize(snapshot, options){
    let json = this._super(...arguments);
    json.tradeIdentifier = json.trade;
    delete json.trade;
    return json;
  }
});
```